# Proving the nondifferentiability of a modified Takagi's blancmange at nondyadic points

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $h(x)=dist(x,2\mathbb{Z})$. The *generalised Takagi-van der Waerden function* $T_{a,b}(x)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a^n h(b^nx)$ is well-known to be continuous at all points of $\mathbb{R}$ yet differentiable nowhere when $a=1/2, b=2$ (when it is known as *Takagi's blancmange*).

We can prove nondifferentiability of Takagi’s blancmange at nondyadic (i.e. $x \neq \frac{\pm p}{2^k}$) points by using the following lemma (proof omitted).

**Lemma:** Let $f$ be defined on an interval $I$ and differentiable at $a \in I$, and let $(a_m), (b_m)$ be sequences in $I$  such that $a_m < a < b_m$ and $\lim_{m\to\infty} a_m=a=b_m$. Then $$ f'(a)=\lim_{m\to\infty} \frac{f(b_m)-f(a_m)}{b_m-a_m} $$

Set $f$ to be $T(1/2,2)$. Now if $a$ is a nondyadic point then there is a sequence $(p_m)$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $$\frac{p_m}{2^m} < a < \frac{p_m+1}{2^m}$$ and $\lim_{m\to\infty} \frac{p_m}{2^m}=a$.

Then $$ \lim_{m\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}h\left(2^n \frac{p_m+1}{2^m}\right)-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}h \left( 2^n \frac{p_m}{2^m}\right)}{\frac{p_m+1}{2^m}-\frac{p_m}{2^m}} $$ $$ =\lim_{m\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{m-n}\left[ h\left(2^{n-m} (p_m+1)\right)-h \left( 2^{n-m} p_m\right)\right] $$
$$ =  \lim_{m\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{m}2^{m-n}\left[ h\left(2^{n-m} (p_m+1)\right)-h \left( 2^{n-m} p_m\right)\right] =  \lim_{m\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{m} \pm 1 $$ which does not converge, and thus $T(1/2,2)$ cannot be differentiable at $a$.

**My question is:** can we prove the nondifferentiability at nondyadic points of the modified Takagi's blancmange $T(1/2,3)$ using the same method?

Then we have $$ \lim_{m\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}h\left(3^n \frac{p_m+1}{2^m}\right)-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}h \left( 3^n \frac{p_m}{2^m}\right)}{\frac{p_m+1}{2^m}-\frac{p_m}{2^m}} $$ $$ = \lim_{m\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{m-n}\left[ h\left( \frac{3^n (p_m+1)}{2^m} \right)-h \left( \frac{3^n p_m}{ 2^{m}} \right)\right], $$ but at this point I am stuck.

This is a slightly academic question, as I know another method of proving nondifferentiability at nondyadic points for $T(1/2,3)$, but I am curious to know if I am missing an obvious way of proceeding from here.